# Is there a way to getElementById from a webView in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get the value of my h1 when id="mode" but it only returns `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null", source: about:blank (1)`. When i try to load the html String directly in the webView it works fine.
Maybe you know the right way to do this.

```
fun getMode(ip: String): String {
    var mode = ""

    wvDevice[0].settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    wvDevice[0].settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    wvDevice[0].settings.databaseEnabled = true



    wvDevice[0].webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('mode').innerHTML")
            { value ->
                val splitted = value.split("\"")
                for (i in splitted.indices){
                    if (splitted[i] == "RGB" || splitted[i] == "TW"){
                        mode = splitted[i]
                        println("mode: $mode")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /*wvDevice[0].loadData("<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n" +
            "<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">\n" +
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\n" +
            "<script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js\"></script>\n" +
            "</head><body><div class=\"container\"><div class=\"row\"><h1 id=\"mode\">TW</h1><h2>533</h2></div>\n" +
            "<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\" href=\"%23\" id=\"change_color\" role=\"button\">Change Color</a> \n" +
            "<input class=\"jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}\" id=\"rgb\" autocomplete=\"off\" style=\"background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\"></div>\n" +
            "<script>function update(picker) {document.getElementById('rgb').innerHTML = Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + ', ' +  Math.round(picker.rgb[1]) + ', ' + Math.round(picker.rgb[2]);\n" +
            "document.getElementById(\"change_color\").href=\"?r\" + Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + \"g\" +  Math.round(picker.rgb[1]) + \"b\" + Math.round(picker.rgb[2]) + \"&\";}</script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</body></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8")*/
    wvDevice[0].loadUrl(ip)


    return mode

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to evaluate it directly, without wrapping it into a function. With your current code you are not executing the function.

```
wvDevice.evalueateJavascript("document.getElementById('mode')", object : ValueCallback<String>() {
    override fun onReceiveValue(value: String) {
        println(value)
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried it but it still returns null. The code looks like this: `override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {

                        wvDevice.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('mode')")


                        { html ->
                            Log.d("HTML", html)
                            // code here
                        }
                    }`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check if it works when you use a ValueCallback interface

Comment: This method also returns null.`wvDevice.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                        wvDevice.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('mode')", object :
                            ValueCallback<String> {
                            override fun onReceiveValue(value: String) {
                                println(value)
                            }
                        })

                    }
                }`

Comment: It might be because you are initiating a new instance. Could you try use view as variable instead of wvDevice

Comment: I've tried this but it still doesn't work for me. `view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('mode')", object :
                            ValueCallback<String> {
                            override fun onReceiveValue(value: String) {
                                println(value)
                            }
                        })`

Comment: Remember that you need to enable javascript: webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true